# Word - Replace text by hyperlinks

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am working on a MS-Word addin that reads the content of a document and replaces every occurence of a specific word by a hyperlink.

So far, I came up with this working algorithm.

```
// Initializes the Find parameters
searchRange.Find.ClearFormatting();
searchRange.Find.Forward = true;
searchRange.Find.Text = "foo";
do
{  
      searchRange.Find.Execute(Wrap: Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop);

      if (searchRange.Find.Found)
      {
           // Creates a Hyperlink at the found location in the current document 
           this.WordDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(searchRange, externalLink, link, "bar");
      }
      searchRange.Find.Execute(Wrap: Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop);
} while (searchRange.Find.Found);
```

This code works, however, it can be slow on bigger documents. Thus, instead of adding hyperlinks one by one, I wanted to simply to use the `Find.Replacement` object and with the `WdReplace.ReplaceAll`property.

However, I cannot manage to replace my search result by a Hyperlink.

Is there a way to replace a piece of text by a hyperlink using the `Replace`method ?
In other words, I'd like to find a way to do this :

`Find.Replacement.Text = new Hyperlink(...);`

On an other side, I've seen that, by hitting `Alt + F9`in Word, we can see hyperlinks as code.
The code looks like this : 
`{ HYPERLINK \l "link" \o "Caption" }`

Another solution would be to be able to set the text replacement as that string and make Word interpret it and thus, create the link.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, fields can only be inserted programmatically, or by using CTRL-F9. There are two possible reasons for this that I see:

- They are not simple text. They have two ranges, the `Code` and the `Result`, only one of which is displayed at any time.
- How else would a user insert text that looks like a code but is not supposed to be one, unless there was a special mechanism to create one?